# Procedure terminating silently when executing prepared statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

### Problem

I have a stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `ProblematicProcedure` (IN dbName varchar(50), IN tableId INT)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v1;
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v2;

    CALL ExecuteSql(CONCAT("CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT * FROM ",dbName,".my_table;"));
    CALL ExecuteSql(CONCAT("CREATE VIEW v2 AS SELECT * FROM ",dbName,".table_",tableId,";"));

    ...
```

When called directly from command line or a client like Navicat or HeidiSql, it **works well**:

```sql
CALL ProblematicProcedure("my_schema",1);
```

But **if called from a custom Apache module** using the exactly same line above, it **crashes** on first `ExecuteSql` call. I have to make it work when called from the Apache module and couldn't find a reason to crash.

### `ExecuteSql` definition

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE ExecuteSql (IN sql_str TEXT)
BEGIN
    SET @query = sql_str;
    PREPARE stm FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stm;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stm;
END
```

### What I tried?

- Swapped two `ExecuteSql` calls.
- Inlined `ExecuteSql` calls.
- Removed `ExecuteSql`'s and used direct SQL statements with hardcoded `dbName` and `tableId` values.
- Created procedure without `MODIFIES SQL DATA`.
- Granted `CREATE VIEW` privilege: `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';`

**Note:** I added simple insert statements between the lines to find where it is crashing. So, I am sure it crashes always on first `ExecuteSql` call.

### Question

**What can be reason to this crash?**

**Update**: Finally, I managed to find error code:

> **ERROR 1312:** Procedure can't return a result set in the given context

Comment: It works also in my machines when called directly. Versions are `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2` and `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.47, for Win64 (unknown)`

Comment: I think you don't need `MODIFIES SQL DATA` try recreating procedure without it. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Use **`CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`** flag when connecting:

```c
mysql_real_connect(conn, host, user, pass, db, 0, NULL, CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS);
```

---

## Why this is so?

Calling a stored procedure means executing multiple statements. So, I need to specify that I can execute multiple statements at once. Hence I am using MySql C API functions at client-side (*in my Apache module*), I need to specify **`CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`** flag when connecting:

```c
mysql_real_connect(conn, host, user, pass, db, 0, NULL, CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS);
```

Or set it later:

```c
mysql_set_server_option(MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON);
```

I learnt those from the **[C API Handling of Multiple Statement Execution](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/mysql-refman/apis.html#c-api-multiple-queries)** page.

---

## How I Debugged?

Debugging a stored procedure is not so easy. I used traditional log-table method, but performed a bit aggresively about finding the error code.

**Firstly**, defined two variables to keep the code and message about the error occurred:

```sql
DECLARE E INT  DEFAULT 0;    -- error code
DECLARE M TEXT DEFAULT NULL; -- error message
```

**Then**, defined possible error codes and messages both for [client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-client.html) and [server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html) errors ([**full list here**](https://gist.github.com/3656288)):

```sql
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1000 SET E='1000', M="hashchk";
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1001 SET E='1001', M="isamchk";
...
...
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1312 SET E='1312', M="PROCEDURE %s can't return a result set in the given context";
...
...
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1638 SET E='1638', M="Non-ASCII separator arguments are not fully supported";
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1639 SET E='1639', M="debug sync point wait timed out";
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1640 SET E='1640', M="debug sync point hit limit reached";
...
...
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 2057 SET E='2057', M="The number of columns in the result set differs from the number of bound buffers. You must reset the statement, rebind the result set columns, and execute the statement again";
```

**And finally**, put logs in critical points:

```sql
IF E> 0 THEN
    CALL WriteLog(CONCAT("Error ", E, ": ", M));
END IF;
```

`WriteLog` is another procedure that only inserts into a log table. This method gave me the error code (`1312`) and then some Googling worked.